# ELDAPv3 - expecting a bstring or an hstring as value for an OCTET STRING

Tags: erlang

I am a newbie to erlang. I am getting this error when I am trying to compile.

ELDAPv3:289: expecting a bstring or an hstring as value for an OCTET STRING

The file: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/asn1/ELDAPv3.asn1~

I have no idea on how to unblock. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give more information how do you compile the file. This is not Erlang source so it has to be parsed with a tool like this one: http://erlang.org/doc/man/asn1ct.html Also, if you read that document just at the beginning it mentions something about your problem, which may suggest incompatibility between Erlang versions. So, please give more information about your environment as well.

Comment: My environment is fine. I did have a lot of errors which I figured except this. I have erlang 17. this is erlang 16 code and making sure that this compiles of 17 and 18 as well. I read that doc as well but havent yet figured a way. 
It is expecting a OCTET or BINARY string but I have given a string as seen by the "". I have a make file since this is a part of a large module.

Answer (score 0):

from [Erlang notes](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/asn1/notes.html):

When specifying the value for an OCTET STRING in a specification, the ASN.1 standard clearly states that the value must be either a bstring or an hstring, but NOT a cstring. The ASN.1 compiler will now generate a compilation error if the value of an OCTET STRING is given as a character string.

That is, the following example is now illegal:

string OCTET STRING ::= "Now illegal"

So please edit the incoming file to change that to real octet strings...
http://pyasn1.sourceforge.net/scalar.html
like this
'4946514654464946524649465250485146494649494646'H